# Как предоставить для windows "образ" файла в виде картинки

Tags: c#, wpf, видео, mp3, mp4

я по не которым причинам соединяю файл mp4 без звука с mp3 файлом, но не используя конвертацию или ffmpeg , т.е. я просто создаю новый файл в начале ставлю маркер моего типа файла, дальше длина mp4 файла и сам файл, потом длина mp3 файла, и сам файл.

так вот я хочу чтобы windows выдавала картинку кадра из файла mp4 при выборе вида "крупные значки", т.е. отдавать Thumbnail. моя программа будет это дело проигрывать, мне надо только чтобы у моего файла тоже было видно картинку как и у mp4 файла

Comment: Начните отсюда: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал используя библиотеку [SharpShell](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell) .
Были трудности с установкой - получилось зарегистрировать используя "ServerManager" который в папке tools по той же ссылке (его нужно запускать от имени Администратора) .